# How to access a variable from a different view controller which is actually a SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a timer inside of the GameScene class's func didMove(toView), now I'm trying to access it from my GameViewController file which is a UIViewController. I tried adding this:

```
var gameScene: GameScene!
```

But it's not working, for example when I try to access the variable after a button is clicked:

```
self.gameScene.timer = timer.etcetc
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to globalise your gameScene like that, this will work:

All I do is make your timer variable more global, and then I can just access it inside your main viewController

```
class GameScene : SKScene {
    var timer: NSTimer!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector(), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}


class Viewcontroller : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var skView = self.view as! SKView
        let gameScene = GameScene()
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)

        gameScene.timer = //whatever

    }
}
```

Comment: But the view controllers are in completely different files?

Comment: That doesn't matter :), a class is a class, you can put two classes in one file or in two separate ones, it's the same .